# Unable to find current post's category jekyll

Tags: jekyll, liquid, jekyll-extensions, jekyll-bootstrap

I want to display keywords and description automatically according to the category of the current post. I've used the following code, but it doesn't worked.

```
{% if page.categories = "category" %}

{% else %}

{% endif %}
```

But while using `{% page.categories %}` it is echoing out the category name correctly. Here are my two doubts:

1. How can I compare the current post's category?
2. Are `{{ }}` and `{% %}` are same here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It should look like the following:

   {% if page.categories == 'some-name' %}

   Hei I am in some-name category

   {% else %}

   No I am not in some-name category

   {% endif %}

2.

No, `{{ }} and {% %}` are not the same. `{{ }}` is used for echoing stuff, while `{% %}` is used for logic expressions and arguments.